# Date Format in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Here is my code. I have 59 CSV files in my directory, I have 11 variables in each, with first one date in quarter format. I need to tell MATLAB that first column has date format, because the code below imports it as a string variable.

```
ext = '.csv';

countries = dir(['*', ext]);
countryFiles = {countries.name};

countriesNames = strrep(countryFiles, ext, '');
%% 

a = cell(length(countriesNames), 2);
a(:,1) = countriesNames(:)';
a(:,2) = cellfun(@(file) readtable(file, 'TreatAsEmpty', '.','Format'?), countryFiles(:), 'uni', 0);
```

As far as I understand this is option 'Format' with datenum in readtable... However, I can`t find useful information on it in helpfiles and whatever I try I get errors... Below how my data looks for each country. Data is 1980Q1-2014Q4.

So I have 59*2 cell array with first column representing countryNames and second column contains 59 140*11  tables. First I do not know how to access variable names within cell array`s table. Second problem is that if you try to define x to a column in that table and then datenum(x,'YYYYQQ') I get "Input expected to be a cell array, was table instead."

So, I need to extract from cell  a tables in a{1,2}, a{2,2}, a{3,2} ... then convert those tables to cellarray using table2cell option. How to do it using loop for each country and then write it back to the cell?

[image]

Comment: That is no supported format, you have to read it using `%s` and convert it in a second step. What do you expect for the conversion? First day of a quater?

Comment: OK if it is possible to do in the next step could you please explain how? I am really unwilling to format cells over again in excel. Is it possible to do inside MATLAB? I just need it in any time-series format so that I could use it further in my work...

Comment: It is possible, but a date in matlab describes one point in time, not a range. What do you expect for the input `1980Q2`? Converting it to `1.4.1980` is a possibility, is this what you want?

Comment: Yes if you could help with that would be great! How do I refer to variable inside a cell in general?

Comment: Thought matlab had no support for quarters, missed that part when I checked the documentation. Maybe `readtable` supports it but I don't know, my matlab version does not have this function. Deleted my answer so hopefully someone else can provide a better answer.